# Como Unir correctamente tres tablas cuando la principal es NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Tengo tres tablas de asistencia, incidencias y faltas.

Las tres tienen el campo de Numero de Empleado y Fecha.

Quiero mostrarlas en un datagrid y estoy utilizando JOIN.

Ya relacione asistencia e incidencias sin problema pero tengo dudas para mostrar faltas en el grid, ya que si existe una falta, no existen datos en asistencias y en incidencias.

El codigo que estoy ultilizando es el siguiente:

```
SELECT Asistencias.Id,Asistencias.NoEmpleado,Asistencias.Fecha,TB_Incidencias.IdCodigo,TB_CodigoIncidencia
FROM Asistencias

OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 Incidencias.IdCodigo
             FROM Incidencias
             WHERE Incidencias.NoEmpleado = Asistencias.[NoEmpleado]
             AND Incidencias.Fecha = RhAsistencias.Fecha ORDER BY Incidencias.Id DESC
             ) TB_Incidencias

OUTER APPLY (SELECT IncidenciasCodigo.Concepto
            FROM IncidenciasCodigo
            WHERE IncidenciasCodigo.Id = TB_Incidencias.IdCodigo
            )TB_CodigoIncidencia

WHERE [RH].[RhAsistencia].[Fecha] = '2018-04-19' ORDER BY [RH].[RhAsistencia].[NoEmpleado]
```

El resultado que me arroja son 15 registros donde 7 de ellos tienen la ultima incidencia que pertenece al numero empleado y la fecha.

La duda es, como relaciono o llamaria la tabla de Faltas ya que no existe un Numero de empleado y fecha en la tabla de asistencias e incidencias cuando existe una falta.

Ya intente con Outer Apply pero no me arroja la unica falta que pertenece a esa fecha ya que el OUTER JOIN esta tomando Asistencias como la tabla principal y se que si no hay datos en asistencias, no me lo va a mostrar.

Cualquier recomendacion o tip, se los agradeceria.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a StackOverflow. Quité etiquetas que estaban de más y puse la etiqueta sql-server, suponiendo que ese es el motor con el que trabajas. Si no lo es, por favor, edita la pregunta, quita esa etiqueta y coloca la etiqueta del motor de base de datos con el que trabajas. Aprovecho para invitarte a hacer el [tour] y de nuevo bienvenido.

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que lo que está buscando es UNION
Así que la columna que quiere usar para el JOIN siempre está NULL en un lado, cualquier tipo de JOIN no va a funcionar.

Para dar un ejemplo simplificado:

Falta:

| NoEmpleado | Fecha | A |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | z |
| 2 | 2020-01-02 | y |
| 1 | 2020-01-03 | x |

Incidente:

| NoEmpleado | Fecha | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 | a |
| 1 | 2020-01-02 | b |
| 2 | 2020-01-03 | c |

Intenta lo siguiente:

```
SELECT [NoEmpleado], [Fecha], [A], CONVERT(varchar(16), NULL) [B]
FROM [Falta]
UNION ALL
SELECT [NoEmpleado], [Fecha], [B], NULL
FROM [Incidente]
ORDER BY [Fecha], [NoEmpleado];
```

Debería resultar en:

| NoEmpleado | Fecha | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | z |  |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 |  | a |
| 2 | 2020-01-02 | y |  |
| 1 | 2020-01-02 |  | b |
| 1 | 2020-01-03 | x |  |
| 2 | 2020-01-03 |  | c |